# Dart:JS: Get a context for a javascript object stored in a bundle generated by browserify

Tags: dart, browserify, dart-js-interop

if I want to integrate some javascript code into Dart I do something like the following:

Javascript Code:

```
function JavaScriptCode()
{
    this['init'] = init;
    function init()
    {
        console.log('init');
    }
}
```

Dart Code:

```
void main()
{
    JsObject jsObject = new JsObject(['JavaScriptCode']);
    jsObject.callMethod('init', []);
}
```

HTML markup:

```
<!-- Html File -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <script src="main.js">
    <script src="main.dart">
</body>
</html>
```

This works fine if main.js is a normal JavaScript file. However, if I run browserfiy over main.js (browserify main.js -o main-bundle.js) to create a bundle, I can no longer get access to the JavaScriptCode object in my Dart code. Is it possible to get access to JavaScript objects that have been bundled using browserify from Dart? And if so how would I go about doing this? Please let me know if the question is unclear.

My aim with this was twofold:
1) I want to manage my JavaScript dependencies better.
2) I want to minimise the amount of JavaScript files that I am loading.

At the moment I have quite a few JavaScript files that my Dart app is working with. Ideally I would have a way to minimise these all into one file.

Comment: It's possible that browserify is mangling the names in the javascript to make it shorter.  If there's an option not to do that, you could try adding that.

Comment: I wouldn't use other bundling tools with dart2js.

Maybe instead you can explain what you're trying to accomplish?